# Laravel: how to include a library?

Tags: php, cross-browser, laravel, user-agent

I want to use the following  :
Holmes in the library folder:

http://paste.laravel.com/Em

```
    // Determine if request is from a mobile device
Holmes::is_mobile(); // returns boolean

// Determine the type of device
$device = Holmes::get_device(); // returns string

// Determine if a specific device is being used
// Any supported device below is acceptable
// lowercased no spaces, obviously. <3
Holmes::is_ipad();
Holmes::is_blackberrytablet();
```

Where do i place what?

in the route:?

View:

```
@if(Holmes::is_iphone())
{{ 'this is an iphone' }}
@endif
```

I get also this error:
Only variables should be passed by reference on line 25 in the Holmes library file

I'm trying to transit from procedural mess ;)

Comment: > Where do i place what?

It has to depends on what you want to do this, can't help without further explaination.

Comment: for example I would like to show/not show an area on my home index.blade.php depending on the device if mobile show X if Desktop show Y

Answer (score 3):

There is a great *article* with instructions on how to load a library in **Laravel 4** by Chris Fidao (Fideloper):
http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading